# redirect image to different image htaccess

Tags: image, .htaccess, redirect

I have tried cpanel redirect but it is not specific. I made a change to my site where anyone using a now old image needs to show a new image. I would like to redirect the link to the old image to the url to the new image.

I have an image
http://mysite.com/images/image.png

When the image is called I want to show
http://mysite.com/images/image.gif

What do I add to htaccess to create this specific rule?

Note that image1 is a png and I am replacing it with a gif so I cant just overwrite with the new image. This is why I am looking for a redirect solution.

EDIT: I can give the image the same name, it will just have different extension.

EDIT 2: change to show image would have the same name, different extension.

Answer (score 1):

A simple URL rewrite should do the trick!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/([a-zA-Z0-9]+).png$ images/$1.gif
```

Whatever is entered here '([a-zA-Z]+)' will be entered here '$1'. Hope that makes sence.
Let me know how you get on!

(Note: there is no rewrite condition to check if the file exists because you want the url rewritten whether there is a file there or not)

Edit:
Probably best to put a .htaccess in the images directory, in this case you can miss out the file paths as you are already in the directory.

Comment: OP use numbers in filename - perheps you need  `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Comment: This rewrites png images to gif images with the same name. e.g., image1.png rewrites to image1.gif, not image2.gif. It is more general-purpose, but depends on what the actual situation is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to replace this one specific image1.png to image2.gif, then this rule should work:

```
RewriteRule ^images/image1.png$ images/image2.gif [NC,L]
```

If you're looking for something more general-purpose, then it depends on your image naming.

Comment: I can give the image the same name, it will just have different extension.

Comment: Then Charlie Walton's answer will work. Please edit your question to show this.